# How do I shorten the run time to complete my problem

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

For context, I am trying to solve this problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/1dfroggerhard

And I exceed the time limit for the problem. Do anyone have tips on how to shorten my run time?
Also, I am a programming noob and this is my first attempt at multiprocessing.
My code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def task(check_tiles, tiles, position, j):
    check_tiles.clear()
    for k in range(len(tiles)):
        check_tiles.append(0)
    magic = tiles[j]
    global wins
    while(True):
        if(tiles[position] == magic):
            wins += 1
            break
        elif((position + tiles[position]) < 0):
            break
        elif((position + tiles[position]) > no_of_tiles - 1):
            break
        else:
            check_tiles[position] = 1
            position += tiles[position]
            if(check_tiles[position] == 1):
                break

no_of_tiles = input()
no_of_tiles = int(no_of_tiles)

wins = 0
tiles = []
check_tiles = []
str2 = input()
tiles = str2.split(' ')
tiles = [int(i) for i in tiles]

for i in range(no_of_tiles):
    position = i
    processes = [Process(target=task(check_tiles, tiles, position, j), args=(j,)) for j in range(no_of_tiles)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
print(wins)
```

I tried to multiprocess the first for-loop but then my answer was wrong.

Comment: python IS single threaded, due to the GIL

Comment: if you `break` the `if` why use `else`/`elif`

Comment: you need to start multiple python instances and let them communicate with sockets

Comment: I don't think the solution lies in parallelizing the code. You are using `input()`, does the time that takes you to type counts as run time?

Comment: You need to review how to construct a Process and start it. If your *task()* function terminates you will effectively be constructing Process with a target of None

Comment: @doneforaiur The input is from a pipe, a file is opened as `stdin`

Comment: you're likely better off using a `Pool` instead of potentially starting thousands of processes (there's no point in using more processes than available CPU cores in compute bound tasks like this, it will likely be counter productive)

Comment: just noticed you're trying to start `n * n` processes.  the problem description says `n` could be 200,000 which would result in you trying to start 40 billion processes.  assuming you can fork 20k processes per second (in practice it will slow down and the system will start swapping very quickly) just starting this many processes would take 23 days.  let alone the work you do inside `task`.  I think you need to approach the problem differently!